# Debugging Javascript with IE9, Visual Studio 2010, MVC3 and Razor syntax

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, debugging, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to get javascript debugging working with IE9 and VS2010.

I've enabled debugging in IE9.

I've made sure that Silverlight debugging is disabled in the project settings.

And placed a breakpoint in my (Razor syntax MVC3) code.

[image: What I've tried]

And nothing happens when I run it :/

This has been happening for a few months now and over many projects, so it's not just that the breakpoint is never reached or something silly and code based.

I've tried:

Uninstalling and resinstalling IE9.

Making sure I have the latest MVC tools so the Razor editor is up to date.

Making the bare minimal amount of code required.

Following all the 'guides' I could find (which are all just variations on what I did above).

Doing the same thing on colleagues machines, and it works.

Manually setting a breakpoint with 'debugger;'. This causes the 'pick your debugger' windows to appear, and in that list I have new or existing VS instances *except* for the one running the site i.e. the one that would do the job.

IE is my default browser.

Comment: Have you tried Chrome? It has a "Developer tools" and "JavaScript console" view.

Comment: Jack: IE has a developer tools and Javascript console view, too.  (Press F12 to get it)   He's trying to use Visual Studio.

Comment: Have you set IE as your default browser? In my experience VS needs to launch the IE session automatically when you debug the project for the JS debugger to work in VS (and will only do so when IE is default).

Comment: whatgoodisaroad: Yep, IE is my default browser, I should have put that in the original post.

Comment: Jack: Chrome is what I usually use, this is why I've put up with this problem for so long. Today I was using the chrome dev tools and it crashed on me which prompted me to try and fix this issue once more. Having debugging with VS working would be ideal for me as I'd then be able to step between the client and server seamlessly.

Comment: In the Internet Options > Advanced settings in IE9, do you have the "Disable script debugging (Internet Explorer)" box checked? Are you using any third party tools that compress scripts (Telerik, AjaxControlToolkit, etc.)?

Comment: Cory: Nope, as the screen shot I included in the question shows, that checkbox is unchecked. And this happens even in the most simple of web apps with nothing third party at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

when you run the application in dot net with IE as a default browser
you can see the solution explorer add up something at last as shown in the black box 
that have the file name being loaded in explorer eg "localhost" here 
just double click on the file you will see the html code as well as the JavaScript there 
now over here you can put the breakpoints and it will work for sure 
[image]

Comment: It still doesn't break on errors though.

I have to manually step though until it just stops working and that indicates where the error is.

Comment: From the horses mouth: "Thanks for your feedback. Currently JS breakpoint mapping to source files in MVC is not supported, and is out of scope for our next release. However we are investigating possible solutions for future release."  http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/652428/mvc-3-mvc-2-debug-ignores-javascript-breakpoints

Comment: See Exziles suggestion in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445558/breakpoints-not-being-hit-in-asp-net-mvc-javascript-event for a workaround.